# Is `event.target` guaranteed to be a descendant of / equal to `this` in event callbacks like "click" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

If I recurse through `.parentNode` of `event.target`, am I guaranteed to reach `this`? Is this mentioned anywhere in the spec?

Here's some code to demonstrate this, which will log if `event.target` is a descendent of `this`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/aRLrG/

```
var isADescendentOf = function (child, parent) {
    if (child === parent) {
        return true;
    }
    if (child === null) {
        return false;
    }
    return isADescendentOf(child.parentNode, parent);
};


var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("*");

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        console.log(isADescendentOf(event.target, this));
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="a">A
    <div id="b">B
        <div id="c">C
            <div id="d">D
                <div id="e">E</div> <span id="f">F</span>

                <button>B</button> <span>1<span>2<span>3
                </span></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

> The event is dispatched to its target `EventTarget` and any event listeners found there are triggered. Bubbling events will then trigger any additional event listeners found by following **the `EventTarget`'s parent chain upward**, checking for any event listeners registered on each successive `EventTarget`. This upward propagation will continue up to and including the `Document`.
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling

Note that there are also non-bubbling events like `focus`, where consequently `event.target == this`.